# c program dumping core on unix

Tags: c, unix, gcc

I am a new learner of C language.

Below program run well on Windows but when i compile with gcc on solaris, this is dumping core

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main()
{
char *name;
name="James Bond";
int i=0;
sprintf(name,"%s/%d",name,i);
printf("String is %s",name);
}
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 6):

You cannot modify a string literal like that, it's undefined according to the standard. You're trying to overwrite that string literal with other data (the `sprintf`).

Many implementations will place them in read-only memory, causing a core dump - they're the good ones. The bad ones will continue on as if everything's okay, which it usually isn't.

You could try the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    char *name;
    char name2[100];  // make sure plenty of space.
    name = "James Bond";
    int i = 0;
    sprintf (name2, "%s/%d", name, i);
    printf ("String is %s\n", name2);
    return 0;
}
```

Most questions of this type have code like:

```
name = "Bob";
*name = 'J';   // to try and make "Job"
```

but it's *just* as undefined to write to string literals using `sprintf` as well.

---

Based on comments, you want to be able tocombine a path and file spec. You could do this as something like:

```
char *path = "/tmp/";
char *file = "xyz.txt"
char fullpath = malloc (strlen (path) + strlen (file) + 1);
if (fullpath == NULL)
    // error and exit condition
strcpy (fullpath, path);
strcat (fullpath, file);
// use fullpath for your nefarious purposes :-)
free (fullpath);
```

That's *one* way to do it, there are others.

Comment: my problem is to hold name of files (~1000). All the files need to be stored with full directory path. I am not sure how it works for long directory path. Can i allocate space based on the directoryPath + filename?? Thanks all for your valuable suggestions

Comment: In C, you can't assign a string making name="JAMES BOND"; You have to use a function like strcpy, strcat or similar.

Answer (score 1):

```
char *name;
name="James Bond";   // name is pointing into read-only memory
int i=0;
sprintf(name,"%s/%d",name,i); // trying to write to read-only memory
printf("String is %s",name);
```

instead use a buffer

```
char name[32] = "James Bond";
...
```

Comment: my problem is that i don't know the size of string coming in and hence defined a pointer

Comment: well the problem was the buffer, not how it is initialized but you are right so I have edited.

Comment: @user977872 well if you have an idea of how long the max length of a string should be you could allocate memory enough using malloc to hold the incoming string(+1) then just copy that string in.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to define and initialize a constan string in C is

```
char name[]="James Bond";
```

Your code may be like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main()
{
    char name[] = "James Bond";
    int i = 0;

        printf("String is %s/%d", name,i);

}
```

Comment: Either "int main( void )" or "int main( int argc, char **argv)" or you are writing for an embedded device.  If you are writing for a hosted environment (eg, windows, linux, unix, etc) you should not use "void main()"

Answer (score 0):

Your "name" string is insufficiently long to hold the set of characters you are printing to it with sprintf - you need to allocate a sufficient buffer for all of the characters.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote for this answer. Whereas the fact that writing into a string literal is UB is certainly a problem, here, the one indicated by John is also a valid concern. This aspect is only implicitly present in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory for `name` pointer using malloc/calloc or defining it as a fixed length variable: `char name[50]` (for example)

Answer (score 0):

On Linux and systems with the GNU Libc, you can also code using *asprintf*

```
char* str = NULL; // pointer should be initialized to NULL
asprintf (&str, "someformat %d", 20);
```

When using GTK, you could also call g_strdup_printf

You should understand the difference and similarities between arrays and pointers in C. Many many books or lectures explain that in detail.

Regards.